# Chern classes of $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

It's known that $S^2$ is a $1$-dimensional complex manifold. Let $\varepsilon^n$ denote the trivial vector bundle of rank $n$, then $TS^2\oplus\varepsilon^1 = \varepsilon^3$, so by the Whitney product formula we have $c(\varepsilon^3)=c(TS^2\oplus\varepsilon^1) = c(TS^2)\cdot c(\varepsilon^1)$ which implies $c(TS^2) = 1$ since $c(\varepsilon^k) = 1$, where $c(E)$ denotes the total Chern classes of $E$. Hence $c_1(TS^2)=0$.

But the top Chern number is $\langle c_1(TS^2), [S^2]\rangle = \chi(S^2)\neq 0$, so what leads to this contradiction?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class#The_complex_tangent_bundle_of_the_Riemann_sphere) says $c_1(TS^2)\neq 0$, so maybe there is something wrong with the Whitney product formula, but I don't see it.

Comment: You're mixing up real and complex vector bundles. $\varepsilon^1$ is only a real line bundle, so it doesn't make sense to talk about its Chern classes. Similary for $\varepsilon^3$.

Comment: and as $c_k(\bar{E})=(-1)^k c_k(E)$, you get $2c_k(V\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C})=0$ for odd $k$ and all real vector bundle $V$.